# PHP inside an "echo". How to do it in this case?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, echo

I'm trying to execute another PHP function inside an echo. I could change

```
<?php echo home_url(); ?>
```

to

```
"$home_url"
```

and it worked.

But I don't know how to change the following:

```
<?php $categories = get_the_category();
    $cat_slug = $categories[0]->slug;
    echo "$cat_slug" ?>
```

Here's my full code, with a HEREDOC instead of " ":

```
<?php   
if( is_page( 3769 ) ):  
    echo 'ANOTHER LOGO';  
else:  
    echo <<<HTML
<a href="$home_url"><img border="0" src="http://WEBSITE.COM/logo<?php $categories = get_the_category();
$cat_slug = $categories[0]->slug;
echo "$cat_slug" ?>
.png" width="500" height="100"></a>
HTML;
endif;     
?>
```

Thank you.

Comment: what!? I don't understand change what

Comment: `<?= get_the_category()[0]->slug ?>`, maybe?

Comment: -1 for horrible formatting. SO shouldn't be a typo-spotting service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you shouldn't execute any functions inside an echo. It's better to do all "preparations" in advance and echo the results. That way it's simpler to split the logic and the presentation later

```
<?php   
if( is_page( 3769 ) ):  
    echo 'ANOTHER LOGO';  
else:  
$categories = get_the_category();
$cat_slug = $categories[0]->slug;
    echo <<<HTML
<a href="$home_url"><img border="0" src="http://WEBSITE.COM/logo{$cat_slug}.png" width="500" height="100"></a>
HTML;
endif;     
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Take the function call out of the string:

```
<?php   
if( is_page( 3769 ) ):  
    echo 'ANOTHER LOGO';  
else:  
    $categories = get_the_category();
    $cat_slug = $categories[0]->slug;
    echo <<<HTML
    <a href="$home_url"><img border="0" src="http://WEBSITE.COM/logo{$cat_slug}.png" width="500" height="100"></a>
    HTML;
endif;     
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use single quote, your `"$cat_slug"` close the first (")

```
src="http://WEBSITE.COM/logo<?php $categories = get_the_category();
$cat_slug = $categories[0]->slug;
echo "$cat_slug" ?>
```

Change it to this:

```
src='http://WEBSITE.COM/logo<?php $categories = get_the_category();
    $cat_slug = $categories[0]->slug;
    echo "$cat_slug" ?>'
```

Comment: That code is in a heredoc, so it doesn't need `<?php ?>` tags. Arbitrary function calls can't be made in strings like that.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code block you supplied I'd have gone with something like this

```
<?php   
if( is_page( 3769 ) ):  
    echo 'ANOTHER LOGO';  
else:
 $categories = get_the_category();
 $cat_slug = $categories[0]->slug;

 echo '<a href="$home_url"><img border="0" src="http://WEBSITE.COM/logo'.$cat_slug.png.'" width="500" height="100"></a>'

endif;     
?>
```

Otherwise you were doing a double echo which is probably causing some issues.